# Android Chart not giving output

Tags: android, charts

Following is my fragment used to display the graph on click of chart button. Right now it does not display any output. There is no error. I am using achartengine for the charts. Is there some error in the code or what? Please help.

```
public class VitalShow extends Fragment{
private Context mContext;
private EditText pn;
private Button chart,vaccine,presc;
private Database dbHelper;
private String val,data,dt,gen;
private View mChart;
private LinearLayout chartContainer;
//private double[] male1,male2,male3,male4,male5;
private String[] mMonth = new String[] {
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"
};
private int agemo;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();
    dbHelper=new Database(getActivity());
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();

    val=bundle.getString("val");
    dt=bundle.getString("dt");
    System.out.println(dt+"Date");
    System.out.println(val+"Valuesss");
    data=dbHelper.getVital(val);
    gen=dbHelper.getGender(val);
    String month=dt.substring(5,8);
    String year=dt.substring(14);
    System.out.println(month+"month"+year+"year");
    System.out.println(gen+"Gender");
    int mono = 0;
   if(month.equals("Jan"))
       mono = 1;
   else if(month.equals("Feb"))
       mono = 2;
   else if(month.equals("Mar"))
       mono = 3;
   else if(month.equals("Apr"))
           mono = 4;
   else if(month.equals("May"))
       mono = 5;
   else if(month.equals("Jun"))
       mono = 6;
   else if(month.equals("Jul"))
       mono = 7;
   else if(month.equals("Aug"))
       mono = 8;
   else if(month.equals("Sep"))
       mono = 9;
   else if(month.equals("Oct"))
       mono = 10;
   else if(month.equals("Nov"))
       mono = 11;
   else if(month.equals("Dec"))
       mono = 12;

       System.out.println(mono+"mono");
     int yrno=Integer.parseInt(year);
     System.out.println(yrno+"yrno");

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     System.out.println(thisMonth+"thisyr");
     agemo=((thisYear-yrno)*12)+(thisMonth-mono+1);
     System.out.println(agemo+"Age");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vitalshow,null);
    pn=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    chart=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    vaccine=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    presc=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    chartContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    pn.setText(data);
    chart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            chart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vaccine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            presc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            openChart(gen);
        }

    });
    vaccine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VaccAdmin.class);
            String mon=String.valueOf(agemo);
            intent.putExtra("age", mon);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    presc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = new Prescription();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("val", val);
            System.out.println(val+"abc");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    });
    return view;
}

private void openChart(String gen){
    String gender=gen;
    System.out.println(gender);
    int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 };
    if(gender.equals("Male")){
    double[] male1 = { 11.3,12.6,13.8, 14.4,14.7,14.8,14.9,14.9,
            14.9,14.8,14.7,14.6,14.5,14.4,14.3,14.2,14.2,14.1,14.0,
            13.9,13.9, 13.8, 13.8, 13.7,13.7};
    double[] male2 = {12.2, 13.6, 14.9, 15.5,15.7,15.9,15.9,15.9,
            15.9,15.8,15.7,15.6,15.5,15.4,15.3,15.2,15.1,15.0,
            14.9,14.8, 14.8, 14.7, 14.6,14.6,14.5};
    double[] male3 = {13.4, 14.9, 16.3,16.9,17.2,17.3,17.3,17.3,
            17.3,17.2,17.0,16.9,16.8,16.7,16.6,16.4,16.3,16.2,16.1,
            16.1,16.0, 15.9, 15.8, 15.8,15.7};
    double[] male4 = {14.8,16.4,17.8,18.5,18.7,18.9,18.9,18.9,
            18.8,18.7,18.6,18.4,18.3,18.1,18.0,17.9,17.8,17.6,17.5,
            17.4,17.4, 17.3, 17.2, 17.1,17.1};
    double[] male5 = {16.1,17.6,19.2,19.8,20.1,20.2,20.3,20.3,
            20.2,20.1,19.9,19.8,19.6,19.5,19.3,19.2,19.1,18.9,18.8,
            18.7,18.6,18.6,18.5,18.4,18.3};
    double[] male6 = {15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,
            15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,};
    // Creating an XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries m1 = new XYSeries("Male1");
    // Creating an XYSeries for Expense
    XYSeries m2 = new XYSeries("Male2");
    // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
    XYSeries m3 = new XYSeries("Male3");
    XYSeries m4 = new XYSeries("Male4");
    XYSeries m5 = new XYSeries("Male5");
    XYSeries m6 = new XYSeries("You");

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    m1.add(i,male1[i]);
    m2.add(i,male2[i]);
    m3.add(i,male3[i]);
    m4.add(i,male4[i]);
    m5.add(i,male5[i]);
    //m6.add(i,male6[i]);
    }
    m6.add(20,15.0);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(m1);
    // Adding Expense Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(m2);
    dataset.addSeries(m3);
    dataset.addSeries(m4);
    dataset.addSeries(m5);
    dataset.addSeries(m6);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED); //color of the graph set to cyan
    incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2f);
    incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting chart value distance
    incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    incomeRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2f);
    expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    expenseRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 


    XYSeriesRenderer Renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Renderer3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Renderer3.setFillPoints(true);
    Renderer3.setLineWidth(2f);
    Renderer3.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    Renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    Renderer3.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

    XYSeriesRenderer Renderer4 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Renderer4.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Renderer4.setFillPoints(true);
    Renderer4.setLineWidth(2f);
    Renderer4.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    Renderer4.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    Renderer4.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

    XYSeriesRenderer Renderer5 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Renderer5.setColor(Color.RED);
    Renderer5.setFillPoints(true);
    Renderer5.setLineWidth(2f);
    Renderer5.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    Renderer5.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    Renderer5.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

    XYSeriesRenderer Renderer6 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Renderer6.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Renderer6.setFillPoints(true);
    Renderer6.setLineWidth(2f);
    Renderer6.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    //setting line graph point style to circle
    Renderer6.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
    Renderer6.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("BMI Chart");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Age in Months");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("BMI percentile");

    /***
    * Customizing graphs
    */
    //setting text size of the title
    multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(28);
    //setting text size of the axis title
    multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(24);
    //setting text size of the graph lable
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(24);
    //setting zoom buttons visiblity
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    //setting pan enablity which uses graph to move on both axis
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    //setting click false on graph
    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
    //setting zoom to false on both axis
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
    //setting lines to display on y axis
    multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
    //setting lines to display on x axis
    multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
    //setting legend to fit the screen size
    multiRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    //setting displaying line on grid
    multiRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    //setting zoom to false
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    //setting external zoom functions to false
    multiRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
    //setting displaying lines on graph to be formatted(like using graphics)
    multiRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    //setting to in scroll to false
    multiRenderer.setInScroll(false);
    //setting to set legend height of the graph
    multiRenderer.setLegendHeight(30);
    //setting x axis label align
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    //setting y axis label to align
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    //setting text style
    multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("sans_serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
    //setting no of values to display in y axis
    multiRenderer.setYLabels(10);
    //multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(10, Color.BLACK);
    // setting y axis max value, Since i'm using static values inside the graph so i'm setting y max value to 4000.
    // if you use dynamic values then get the max y value and set here
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(20);
    //setting used to move the graph on xaxiz to .5 to the right
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
    //setting used to move the graph on xaxiz to .5 to the right
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(24);
    //setting bar size or space between two bars
    //multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    //Setting background color of the graph to transparent
    multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    //Setting margin color of the graph to transparent
    //multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_background));
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multiRenderer.setScale(2f);
    //setting x axis point size
    multiRenderer.setPointSize(4f);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(90);
    //setting the margin size for the graph in the order top, left, bottom, right
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30, 30, 30, 30});
    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
    multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
    }

    // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer3);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer4);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer5);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer6);
    //this part is used to display graph on the xml
    //LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart);
    //remove any views before u paint the chart
    chartContainer.removeAllViews();
    //drawing bar chart
    mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, multiRenderer);
    //adding the view to the linearlayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart,new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
else {
     double [] female1 = { 11.2, 12.1, 13.2, 13.7,14.0,14.2,14.3,14.3,
             14.3,14.2,14.1,14.0,13.9,13.8,13.7,13.7,13.6,13.5,13.4,
             13.4,13.3, 13.3, 13.3, 13.2,13.2};
        double [] female2 = {12.1, 13.2, 14.3, 14.9,15.2,15.3,15.4,15.4,
                15.4,15.3,15.2,15.1,15.0,14.8,14.7,14.6,14.6,14.5,
                14.4,14.3, 14.3, 14.2, 14.2,14.2,14.1};
        double [] female3 ={13.3, 14.6,15.8,16.4,16.7,16.8,16.9,16.9,16.8,
                16.7,16.6,16.5,16.4,16.2,16.1,16.0,15.9,15.8,15.7,15.7,15.6,
                15.5,15.5, 15.4, 15.4};
        double [] female4 = {14.7, 16.1, 17.4, 18.0,18.3,18.5,18.6,18.6,
                18.5,18.4,18.2,18.1,17.9,17.8,17.7,17.5,17.4,17.3,17.2,
                17.2,17.1, 17.0, 17.0, 16.9,16.9};
        double [] female5 = {15.9, 17.3, 18.8, 19.4,19.8,20.0,20.1,20.1,
                20.0,19.9,19.7,19.6,19.4,19.2,19.1,19.0,18.8,18.7,18.6,
                18.5,18.5, 18.4, 18.3, 18.3,18.2};

        // Creating an XYSeries for Income
        XYSeries m1 = new XYSeries("Female1");
        // Creating an XYSeries for Expense
        XYSeries m2 = new XYSeries("Female2");
        // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
        XYSeries m3 = new XYSeries("Female3");
        XYSeries m4 = new XYSeries("Female4");
        XYSeries m5 = new XYSeries("Female5");
        XYSeries m6 = new XYSeries("You");

        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        m1.add(i,female1[i]);
        m2.add(i,female2[i]);
        m3.add(i,female3[i]);
        m4.add(i,female4[i]);
        m5.add(i,female5[i]);
        }
    m6.add(12,14.0);
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(m1);
        // Adding Expense Series to dataset
        dataset.addSeries(m2);
        dataset.addSeries(m3);
        dataset.addSeries(m4);
        dataset.addSeries(m5);
        dataset.addSeries(m6);

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED); //color of the graph set to cyan
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2f);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting chart value distance
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        incomeRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2f);
        expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        expenseRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 


        XYSeriesRenderer Renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        Renderer3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Renderer3.setFillPoints(true);
        Renderer3.setLineWidth(2f);
        Renderer3.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        Renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        Renderer3.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

        XYSeriesRenderer Renderer4 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        Renderer4.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        Renderer4.setFillPoints(true);
        Renderer4.setLineWidth(2f);
        Renderer4.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        Renderer4.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        Renderer4.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

        XYSeriesRenderer Renderer5 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        Renderer5.setColor(Color.RED);
        Renderer5.setFillPoints(true);
        Renderer5.setLineWidth(2f);
        Renderer5.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        Renderer5.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        Renderer5.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

        XYSeriesRenderer Renderer6 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        Renderer6.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Renderer6.setFillPoints(true);
        Renderer6.setLineWidth(2f);
        Renderer6.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        //setting line graph point style to circle
        Renderer6.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        //setting stroke of the line chart to solid
        Renderer6.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID); 

        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("BMI Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Age in Months");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("BMI percentile");

        /***
        * Customizing graphs
        */
        //setting text size of the title
        multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(28);
        //setting text size of the axis title
        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(24);
        //setting text size of the graph lable
        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(24);
        //setting zoom buttons visiblity
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        //setting pan enablity which uses graph to move on both axis
        multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        //setting click false on graph
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        //setting zoom to false on both axis
        multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        //setting lines to display on y axis
        multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
        //setting lines to display on x axis
        multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        //setting legend to fit the screen size
        multiRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
        //setting displaying line on grid
        multiRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        //setting zoom to false
        multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        //setting external zoom functions to false
        multiRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
        //setting displaying lines on graph to be formatted(like using graphics)
        multiRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
        //setting to in scroll to false
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(false);
        //setting to set legend height of the graph
        multiRenderer.setLegendHeight(30);
        //setting x axis label align
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        //setting y axis label to align
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        //setting text style
        multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("sans_serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
        //setting no of values to display in y axis
        multiRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        //multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(10, Color.BLACK);
        // setting y axis max value, Since i'm using static values inside the graph so i'm setting y max value to 4000.
        // if you use dynamic values then get the max y value and set here
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(20);
        //setting used to move the graph on xaxiz to .5 to the right
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
        //setting used to move the graph on xaxiz to .5 to the right
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(24);
        //setting bar size or space between two bars
        //multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        //Setting background color of the graph to transparent
        multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        //Setting margin color of the graph to transparent
        //multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_background));
        //multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multiRenderer.setScale(2f);
        //setting x axis point size
        multiRenderer.setPointSize(4f);
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(90);
        //setting the margin size for the graph in the order top, left, bottom, right
        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30, 30, 30, 30});
        multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
        // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
        // should be same
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer3);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer4);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer5);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Renderer6);
        //this part is used to display graph on the xml
        //LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart);
        //remove any views before u paint the chart
        chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        //drawing bar chart
        mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, multiRenderer);
        //adding the view to the linearlayout
        chartContainer.addView(mChart,new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
}

}
```